# Using letters as <td id's> (beginner question)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I know this is maybe some kind of a beginner question, but hours of googling doesn't seem to help me.

My given script works fine if I use numbers e.g.  but with letters e.g.  it doesn't. Anyone can help ?

```js
function change($cells) {
  
  $cells.forEach(e => document.getElementById(e).classList.add('setbg'));
  
}
```

```css
table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 25px;
}

.setbg {
    background-color: yellow;    
}
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
        <td id="1">1</td>
        <td id="A_1">2</td>
        <td id="A">3</td>
        <td id="1_A">4</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 
 <button onclick="change([1])">
 works fine
 </button>
 
  <button onclick="change([A_1, A, 1_A])">
doesn't work
 </button>
```

Comment: You need to pass strings: `change(['A_1', 'A', '1_A'])`. Note that older browsers may have problems with IDs that start with numbers...

Comment: Oh god, thank you :'D